# ContentLoadException in Monogame for Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, monogame

**I can´t load Images in Monogame for android Using Xamarin**, and am receiving the following exception:

> ExceptionMicrosoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException: The content file was not found.

I've changed the files to "Copy if newer" and "Android Asset" and added them to both assets and content.  I also verified that when I use the Monogame Pipeline, the file, "WowperroFirmaWhite.xnb", is generated under "bin\Android\Content".

I am following this monogame [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CcPb0bKkpeg&list=PLHJE4y54mpC5hrlDv8yFHPfrSNhqFoA0h&index=2); I've also tried loading the image to a new project, but I still can't.

#### This is my Solution Explorer

[image: Solution Explorer Screenshot].

And last but not least - here is my code

```cpp
 public class SplashScreen : GameScreen
    {
        Texture2D image;
        string path;
        public override void LoadContent()
        {
         try
            {
                path = "WowperroFirmaWhite";
                image = content.Load<Texture2D>(path);               
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("EXCEPTION");
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
```

I also set

```cpp
 public class GameScreen
    {
        protected ContentManager content;
        public virtual void LoadContent()
        {
            content = new ContentManager(ScreenManager.Instance.Content.ServiceProvider, "Content");
        }
```

And on Main

```cpp
 public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

            graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 800;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 480;
            //graphics.SupportedOrientations = DisplayOrientation.LandscapeLeft | DisplayOrientation.LandscapeRight;
            graphics.SupportedOrientations = DisplayOrientation.Portrait;
        }
```

Then

```cpp
protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            ScreenManager.Instance.LoadContent(Content);
        }
```

And on Draw

```cpp
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            spriteBatch.Begin();

            ScreenManager.Instance.Draw(spriteBatch);

            spriteBatch.End();  

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
```

In my content.mgbc

```
#----------------------------- Global Properties ----------------------------#

/outputDir:bin/$(Platform)
/intermediateDir:obj/$(Platform)
/platform:Android
/config:
/profile:Reach
/compress:False

#-------------------------------- References --------------------------------#


#---------------------------------- Content ---------------------------------#

#begin WowperroFirmaWhite.png
/importer:TextureImporter
/processor:TextureProcessor
/processorParam:ColorKeyColor=255,0,255,255
/processorParam:ColorKeyEnabled=True
/processorParam:GenerateMipmaps=False
/processorParam:PremultiplyAlpha=True
/processorParam:ResizeToPowerOfTwo=False
/processorParam:MakeSquare=False
/processorParam:TextureFormat=Color
/build:WowperroFirmaWhite.png
```

In case you want to see full project, here is my solution on [Github](https://github.com/WoWPerro/King-s_Tiles)

Comment: Your folder structure seems a bit weird, Why are there 2 content folders? The xnb files itself do not belong in the root content folder. They will be created in the bin folder automatically and read from there.

Comment: The exception will tell you the exact path the file was not found in.  Remove the `try/catch` and execute with a debugger attached. Move the file to the specified directory.